# Catalog Product View

Tags: product, catalog, product-view

I have this weird situation with displaying products in Magento. I have a file called `cataloq.xml` loclated in my theme folder called `layout` and I have the code bellow inside **catalog_product_view tag:**

```
        <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/lp_view_page.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

When I visit my home/index page and click on the product it is displayed in `lp_view_page.phtml` template file, which is ok. But when I try to open this same product from category list/grid view, Magento doesn't use `lp_view_page.phtml` template, it use template page for listening category products in list/grid view (`lp_laptopi_list.phtml`).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Bellow code should be insered into category -> custom design (field: Custom Layout Update)

```
        <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/lp_view_page.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

and option apply to all product should be to "no"!

good luck! :)